# Finding a part of a string in another string variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have an issue in finding a part of string variable in another string variable, I tried many methods but none worked out..

for example:

```
echo -e "   > Required_keyword: $required_keyword"
send_func GUI WhereAmI
echo -e "   > FUNCVALUE: $FUNCVALUE"

flag=`echo $FUNCVALUE|awk '{print match($0,"$required_keyword")}'`;

if [ $flag -gt 0 ];then

    echo "Success";
else
    echo "fail";

fi
```

But it always gives **fail** though there are certain words in variable which matches like

> 0_Menu/**BAA_Record**  ($required_keyword output string)
>
> Trying to connect to 169.254.98.226 ... OK! Executing sendFunc GUI
>   WhereAmI Sent Function WhereAmI [OK PageName:
>   "_0_Menu__47__**BAA_Record**" ($FUNCVALUE output string)

As we can see here the **BAA_Record** is common in both of the output still, it always give **FAIL**

The output echo is

```
   > Required_keyword: 0_Menu/BAA_Record
   > FUNCVALUE: 
Trying to connect to 169.254.98.226 ... OK!


Executing sendFunc GUI WhereAmI 
Sent Function WhereAmI [OK]
PageName: "_0_Menu__47__BAA_Record"
```

Comment: Shell variables do not get expanded in single quotes (like the ones you wrapped around your `awk` script).

Comment: Can you give the exact input string and whats your expected result?

Comment: @Ram I have edited the question hope its more clearer

Answer (score 2):

Bash can do wildcard and regex matches inside double square brackets.

```
if [[ foobar == *oba* ]]    # wildcard

if [[ foobar =~ fo*b.r ]]   # regex
```

In your example:

```
if [[ $FUNCVALUE = *$required_keyword* ]]

if [[ $FUNCVALUE =~ .*$required_keyword.* ]]
```

Comment: I tried the following `if [[ $FUNCVALUE == *$required_keyword* ]]
then
    echo "found"
else
    echo "no match"
fi` But it says no **no match**

Comment: In your question, `$required_keyword` is `0_Menu/BAA_Record` but `$FUNCVALUE` contains `0_Menu__47__BAA_Record` with the slash `/` replaced by `__47__`. Is that the problem?

Comment: Not only that but also it doesn`t contain the `0_Menu` I just tried to grep the output and save it a file as `echo  "   > FUNCVALUE: $FUNCVALUE" > func.xml` and manually add `/0_Menu/BAA_Record` It works fine, now. How can I make it work without doing any alterations such as I made now...?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you want, but if you need to find out if there's part of string "a" present in variable "b" you can use simply just grep.

```
grep -q "a" <<< "$b"

[[ "$?" -eq 0 ]] && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"
```

EDIT: To clarify, grep searches for string a in variable b and returns exit status (see man grep, hence the -q switch). After that you can check for exit status and do whatever you want (either with my example or with regular if statement).

Comment: I tried `grep -q "$required_keyword" <<< "$FUNCVALUE"` with an echo as mentioned `[[ "$?" -eq 0 ]] && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"` but I get the result as not found. Though as mentioned **BAA_Record ** is common in both of the output

Comment: Yeah, after that you need to check for exit status, variable "?" will contain either zero or one. If it contains zero, the string was found, if it contains one, nothing was found. Consult "man grep".

Comment: Then it wasn't found. Can you post the strings and the related *actual* part of the script ?

Comment: Hi, I have edited my original question, I hope it more clearer. The script I execute is `echo -e "   > Required_keyword: $required_keyword"
send_func GUI WhereAmI
echo -e "   > FUNCVALUE: $FUNCVALUE"`

Comment: The output echo is `> Required_keyword: 0_Menu/BAA_Record
   > FUNCVALUE: 
Trying to connect to 169.254.98.226 ... OK!


Executing sendFunc GUI WhereAmI 
Sent Function WhereAmI [OK]
PageName: "_0_Menu__47__BAA_Record"
`